# Obtain PDE by eliminating arbitrary functions in $x=f(z(x,y))+g(y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $z=z(x,y)$ and 
>   $$x=f(z)+g(y)$$
>   Eliminate the arbitrary functions to obtain a PDE.

The answer is $ps=qr$ where $p=z_x, q=z_y, r=z_{xx}, s=z_{xy}$.

But I couldn't even reach close to this answer. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let us compute the partial derivatives of $x = f+g$:
\begin{aligned}
1 &= f' z_x &         0 &= f' z_y+ g' \\
0 &= f'' (z_x)^2 + f' z_{xx} &            0 &= f'' (z_y)^2 + f' z_{yy} + g'' \\
0 &= f'' z_x z_y + f' z_{xy} &            0 &= f'' z_x z_y + f' z_{xy}
\end{aligned}
Consider the system satisfied by the derivatives of $f$, $g$, where the partial derivatives of $z$ act as coefficients. We have got five (linear) equations of four unknowns $f'$, $g'$, $f''$, $g''$. Thus, this non-homogeneous system is [overdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system). If all equations are linearly independent, then there is no solution. Therefore, we can derive at least one additional equation that links the coefficients -- i.e. the partial derivatives of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Given x=f(z) +g(y).     ... (i)

Differentiating with respect to x and y,

```
                     1=(∂f/∂z)(∂z/∂x)

      =>(∂f/∂z)(∂z/∂x)=1   ...(ii) 
                     
               0=(∂f/∂z)(∂z/∂y)+g'(y)
```

(∂f/∂z)(∂z/∂y)+g'(y)=0    ... (iii)

Differentiating (ii) with respect to x,then

```
         ∂/∂x((∂f/∂z).(∂z/∂x))=0
```

=>∂/∂z(∂f/∂z).((∂f/∂z).(∂z/∂x))+(∂f/∂z)(∂²z/∂x²)=0     ... (iv)

Differentiating (ii) with respect to x,then

```
         ∂/∂x((∂f/∂z).(∂z/∂y))+0=0
```

=>∂/∂x.(∂/∂z).((∂f/∂z).(∂z/∂y))+(∂f/∂z).(∂²z/∂x∂y)=0
=>(∂²f/∂z).((∂f/∂z).(∂z/∂y))+(∂f/∂z).(∂²z/∂x∂y)=0  ... (v)

From (iv) and (v), (we will finding determinate)

```
    |(∂z/∂x)²               ∂²z/∂x² |
    |                               |
```

=>      |                               |=0
|                               |
|(∂z/∂x).(∂z/∂y)        ∂²z/∂x∂y|

```
    |   p²                      r   |
    |                               |
```

=>      |                               |=0
|                               |
|   pq                      s   |

=> p²s-pqr=0
=> ps-qr=0.

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).